# Unable to scroll until bottom

Tags: unity-game-engine

I tried to follow this link to create a scrollable UI: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ArH0S2Cdptk&t=21s&ab_channel=AlexanderZotov

If I use Text, it is working as expected. But if I use TextMeshPro, it won't scroll until bottom.

When Loaded it look like this

[image]

When I scroll down normally, it only reaches up to this point.

[image]

If I try to force the scroll, it would reach here but if I release my scroll, it will return to the 2nd image.

[image]

Here's my objects:

[image]

My text container is connected to TMP rect.

[image]

Why is it that it won't go to the bottom normally when I scroll?
Note: The height of the TMP has the whole text included without any truncation.

Comment: Shouldn't I use a `ScrollView` component?

Comment: Hi Isaac, thank you for your response. But I just followed the video I just watched. He is using Scroll Rect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, if I just use the exact height of my text, it won't work. But if I just doubled the height, it is working as my expectation.